# Using multi-select css' select patterns in Angular By.css doesn't give multiple elements

Tags: angular-test

In `css`, I could do `a[href^="https"]` which Selects every `<a>` element whose `href` attribute value begins with "https". How can I specify same rule in `By.css` in `Angular`?

`By.css` is defined in https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/By as

`static css(selector: string): Predicate<DebugElement>`

My `Angular` code has several `div`s with `id` attribute equal to `thumbnail-1`, `thumbnail-2`. I want to get all of them in my `Jasmine` unit test.

At the moment, I am collecting them individually

`let imageThumbnailDiv1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));`
`let imageThumbnailDiv2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-2"));`

If I use the multi-select pattern, I get only the 1st element. Is there a way to get multiple elements.

```
  fit('select all thumbnails',(done)=>{
      let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
      let imageThumbnailDivs = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("div[id^=\"thumbnail\"]"));
      console.log("thumbnail divs before file upload ",imageThumbnailDivs);
      expect(imageThumbnailDivs).toBeFalsy();

      let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");
      let file2 = new File(["foo2"], "foo2.txt");
      let file3 = new File(["foo3"], "foo3.txt");
      //let file4 = new File(["foo4"], "foo4.txt");
      let reader1 = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);
      let reader2 = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file2]);
      let reader3 = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file3]);

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("in timeout");

        fixture.detectChanges();//without this, the view will not be updated with model
        let imageThumbnailDivsAfter = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("div[id^=\"thumbnail\""));
        console.log("thumbnail divs after file upload ",imageThumbnailDivsAfter); //<-- this shows only the 1st element
        expect(imageThumbnailDivsAfter).toBeTruthy();
        //console.log("before done call")
        done();//without done, jasmine will finish this test spec without checking the assertions in the timeout
        //console.log("after timeout call")
      }, 2000);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debugElement.queryAll` instead of `debugElement.query` to get an array over which you can iterate.

```
let thumbnails = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css(".thumbnail"));

thumbnails.forEach((debugElement)=>{
    expect(debugElement)//Whatever you want to test
})
```